# How to determine the cell size of a nested table cell in VBA for Microsoft Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, nested-table

It seems that VBA retrieves a false value for the cell height of a nested table cell.
The primary table

After selecting a form field, I try to get position and size (x1,y1,x2,y2) with the following code:

```
ActiveDocument.Fields(xx).Select  ' Fields(xx) element is inside a cell of a nested table
x1 = Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage) - (Selection.Cells.Width / 2)
x2 = Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage) + (Selection.Cells.Width / 2)
y1 = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) + (Selection.Cells.Height / 2) + (Selection.font.SIZE / 2)
y2 = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) - (Selection.Cells.Height / 2) + (Selection.font.SIZE / 2)
```

With a regular table Selection.Cells.Height returns the correct value.
With a nested table Selection.Cells.Height returns 9999999 instead of the real value.

Is there a workaround to determine the cell height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Height property returns 9999999 because the **HeightRule** default to the [WdRowHeightRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrowheightrule).wdRowHeightAuto(ie. = 0). It doesn't matter if it's a nested table or not. So if you want to get the exact value of the Height property, You first should set the value of [HeightRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.cells.heightrule) to not wdRowHeightAuto( wdRowHeightAtLeast =1 or wdRowHeightExactly =2) before reading this property.

Suppose your Height is set to 0.42 cm, then your code should be like this:

```vb
Sub t()
    Dim x1, x2, y1, y2
    ActiveDocument.Fields(xx).Select  ' Fields(xx) element is inside a cell of a nested table
    With Selection.Cells
        .HeightRule = wdRowHeightAtLeast
        '.Height = CentimetersToPoints(0.42)
    End With
    x1 = Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage) - (Selection.Cells.Width / 2)
    x2 = Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage) + (Selection.Cells.Width / 2)
    y1 = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) + (Selection.Cells.Height / 2) + (Selection.Font.Size / 2)
    y2 = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) - (Selection.Cells.Height / 2) + (Selection.Font.Size / 2)
End Sub
```